# How to use both bash and zsh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu-14.04, zsh

I used Zsh before (on Ubuntu 14.04). But I do something wrong and I can't check `ruby -v` anymore. So I'm trying install rvm, ruby, rails again.

But nothing happen, I can't still check `ruby -v`.

So I used `bash --login` and everything fine for me.

But when I turn off terminal. Problem happen again so I have to use `bash --login`.

I want to use ZSH but I can't check ruby version. How I can do both of them ???

For more detail, I will show you some infomation that may usefull:(When I using ZSH)

> $echo $PATH
>
> /home/phuocdh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/bin
>
> $ruby -v
>
> ```
>  zsh: command not found: ruby
> ```
>
> $rvm -v
>
> ```
>  rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
> ```
>
> $rvm list
>
> ```
>  rvm rubies
>
>    ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
> =* ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]
> ```

In `bash --login`:

> $echo $PATH
>
> /home/phuocdh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/bin:/home/phuocdh/.rvm/bin

Anyone can help me resolve this? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There are likely something in your `.bashrc` et al that needs to go in your `.zshrc` or something in your `.zshrc` that needs to be removed. Compare them and see what you get.

Comment: Please share an output of `rvm list` in `zsh`.

Comment: You probably have the `$PATH` environment variable not correctly setup. Check `~/.zshrc` and `~/.zprofile` and compare with `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. Compare `echo $PATH` in both zsh and bash.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I updated.

Comment: @kba PATH in zsh and bash is different. How can I fix it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I find an answer for my problem.

I just need to change PATH of `~/.zshrc` by bash PATH.